# How do I reverse a named Django URL to the urlpattern that defines it?

Tags: python, django, url-routing

My Django app contains a couple of external references, e.g. to the application's blog, which is not part of the Django codebase and is hosted on a different subdomain.

So far, links to these were spread all around the source code as direct absolute URLs.

Now I was wondering if there was a way to use Django's excellent URL routing system for these external URLs as well. I thought I could define them like this:

```
url(r'^permalink/blog/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='https://blog.example.com'), name='blog'),
```

Then I could just reference them as `{% url 'blog' %}` in my templates. That works.

---

Now I was wondering if there was a way to resolve these directly to the 'final' URL with a special (self-defined) template tag, so that they appear as `https://blog.example.com` to the user, as opposed to `/permalink/blog/` (to the browser) or `https://app.example.com/permalink/blog/` (to the user). I do already have a self-defined `{% absolute_url %}` template tag, which I use in templates that require absolute URLs, like transactional email.

However, I couldn't find a way to reverse a named URL (like `external:blog`) to its urlpattern as opposed to its final relative URL. To do this myself, it seems like I'd have to duplicate all the code from `URLNode.render()`, plus `urlresolvers.reverse` plus probably parts of `RegexURLResolver._reverse_with_prefix()`. That's quite a bunch of code, but I didn't see a simpler entry point/hook into the system. Did I miss a trick there?

---

To summarize, I'm basically looking for a function that I can pass a named URL to, e.g.

```
external:blog
```

and get a `RegexURLPattern` instance back, e.g.

```
RegexURLPattern(r'^permalink/blog/$', RedirectView('https://blog.example.com'), {}, 'blog')
```

or maybe just the view might work, too.

Comment: check `sites` framework for Django - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/#getting-the-current-domain-for-full-urls

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I don't see a connection between the link you posted and my question. Please elaborate as an answer!